# PHPMailer cannot send to pop3 emails (VestaCP)

Tags: dns, smtp, phpmailer, pop3, exim4

For the past few days i'm trying to config PHPMailer to send emails to our new clients. Everything seems to work with imap but when i try to send to a pop3 email i don't get any error and i don't receive any email. My smtp server is under the same machine (made with VestaCP using exim4) pop3 is under dovecot.

Here is the current code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->setFrom('backoffice@xdomain.lu', 'Backoffice');
$mail->addAddress('mail@pop3mail.lu');   // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('backoffice@xdomain.lu', 'Backoffice');
$mail->isHTML(true);               // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Nouveau Contrat eida';
$mail->Body    = '<b>body</b>;
$mail->AltBody = "body"
```

From what i saw i don't need to add any host server because it will use my localhost server (that is working!)

I think that i need to change some stuff on my DNS (i didn't touched it for pop3 so far since i'm not sure what to add exacly)
Firewall is also working because i can telenet pop3 port.

If someone out there could give me DNS hints it would be amazing

Thank you

Comment: You seem a bit confused - POP3 is a means of picking up messages, not sending them. You're sending via a local mail server, so you need to check your local mail server logs.

Comment: Thanks for he reply, my smtp is local so i dont need any phpmailer configuration but if nothing seems wrong, not eveb debugging error messages are shown why isnt it sending to pop3 emails? (By this i mean that those emails have not imap option

Comment: It’s nothing to do with POP3. There’s no SMTP debug output because you’re not using SMTP. Read your mail server logs, like I said.